# Javascript RegEx with variable to check for naming format

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been trying to get a regex working where I can check whether the naming scheme of an ID follows the correct format. But I want to be able to change the format using a variable. The regex combination itself works, but as soon as I tried to add in a variable, it seems to stop functioning. This version seems to work:

```js
const id = $("#div-1-name-1").attr("id");
const regex = new RegExp(/^div-\d-name-\d$/);

console.log(regex.test(id)); // returns true as expected
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div-1-name-1"></div>
```

But as soon as I want to make "name" a variable, so I can interchange this using a function later on, it seems to stop working. For some reason, it always seems to return false.

```js
const id = $("#div-1-name-1").attr("id");
const variableName = "name";
const regex = new RegExp(`/^div-\d-${variableName}-\d$/`);

console.log(regex.test(id)); // returns false, where true expected
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div-1-name-1"></div>
```

Am I perhaps inserting the variable in a wrong way? I cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: ``const regex = new RegExp(String.raw`^div-\d-${variableName}-\d$`);``

Comment: Wiktor, if you don’t mind, I’ve added your suggestion as an alternative way for my answer, if you want I can remove it and you can create your own answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the regex string and remove the`/` from the start and the end like this:

```js
new RegExp(`^div-\\d-${variableName}-\\d$`);
```

Or as [Wiktor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew) commented

```js
new RegExp(String.raw`^div-\d-${variableName}-\d$`);
```

Comment: The top method didn't seem to work either for. Tried that earlier before. But the String.Raw apparently does work. Thanks! Also thanks for Wiktor to give this answer.

Comment: I updated my answer please try again the top solution

Comment: That also seems to work, thank you!